# Gatsby image fluid set to max-height

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

How can I set the height of an image in gatsby? My approach was this:

```
My query:
           image {
              fluid {
                ...GatsbyContentfulFluid_withWebp
            }
            }

My return:
          <Img fluid={image.fluid} style={{ maxHeight: '200px' }} alt={title}></Img>
```

The image is displaying fine but I query more than one image and using style={{ maxHeight: '200px' }} is not working for all images. Some images having different heights, I would like to display all images with the same height.

What's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Did you use `height: '200px', width: 'auto'` (not `maxHeight`)? Maybe you are looking for a fixed image, not fluid...

Comment: I think you're right, should try fixed instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a fixed image, not fluid:

```
My query:
           image {
              fixed {
                ...GatsbyContentfulFixed_withWebp
            }
            }

My return:
          <Img fixed={image.fixed} style={{ height: '200px', width: 'auto' }} alt={title}></Img>
```

In addition, use the `height`, not the `maxHeight` property to force all image's `height` to `200px`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs you should use [`imgStyle`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image#gatsby-image-props) property for directly applying styles to underlying `<img>`

Try something like

```
<Img
 fluid={image.fluid}
 imgStyle={{ height: '200px', width: 'auto' }}
 alt={title}>
</Img>
```

`style` is applied to wrapper of `<img>` and your images might be overflowing it.

Comment: Still not having the same height tho, trying something else..